# select count of rows minus sum of another field

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have three tables named `agency`, `works` and `purchases`. and there is a Foreign Key from `agency` in `purchases` and `works`. every agency works for us and those works are saved in `works` table and will give one point per each works that they do. for example an agency does 200 works for us, so it has 200 points.
each agency can buy our product by their points. in `purchases` table there is a field named `price`, if an agency buy a product it will insert into `purchases` table.
i need a SQL query that give me the number of works of each Agency minus sum of its purchases!

Like:

```
select count(works.WID)-SUM(purchases.price) where agency.aid='1'
```

for example:
agency like this:

```
 AID='1' name='FirstAgency'
```

do some works like:

```
WID='1' AID='1' Description='Clean the floor'  
WID='2' AID='1' Description='Clean the window' 
WID='3' AID='1' Description='Clean the floor'  
WID='4' AID='1' Description='Clean the window' 
WID='5' AID='1' Description='Clean the floor'  
WID='6' AID='1' Description='Clean the window'
```

so the FirstAgency has 6 points because there are 6 rows with AID='1' in `Works` table
and FirstAgency bought a product that the products price is 2. like this in `Purchases` table:

```
PID='1' AID='1' Price='2'
```

so this agency has 6-2=4 points now. I need a query to do this, compute remainder of agency points.

Comment: What problems do you have writing such a query?

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  That is often the most effective way to communicate what's needed.

Comment: What query did you try and why are you not satisfied with the result or what error occurs?

Comment: Get some idea,
select COUNT(*) from agency inner join work  on agency.col=work=col
where not exists
(
select SUM(purchases.price) from purchases  where  agency.col=purchases=col
group by agencyid
)
group by agencyid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem is that you have n works and m purchases and you don't want to join the tables, because you would suddenly be confronted with n * m records.

You can do this:

```
select
  (select count(*) from works w where w.id_agency = a.id_agency) as count_works,
  (select sum(p.price) from purchases p where p.id_agency = a.id_agency) as sum_purchases
from agency a
where a.id_agency = 1;
```

This is also possible with joins, but you would need some math which would obfuscate the statement. I'll just show it for completeness' sake.

```
select
  count(distinct w.id_work) as count_works,
  coalesce(sum(p.price),0) / greatest(count(distinct w.id_work),1) as sum_purchases
from agency a
left join works w on w.id_agency = a.id_agency
left join purchases p on p.id_agency = a.id_agency
where a.id_agency = 1;
```

Comment: Just curious, but when was `greatest` added to the SQL-language?

Comment: @NickyvV: I don't think it is standard, but many dbms support it (Oracle, Postgres, MySQL, etc.).

Comment: *greatest* is not supported by sql server

Comment: @Thomas Haratyk: Ah, okay, I missed the SQL Server tag. No problem, however, because all it does here is replace a zero with a one. This can be replaced with a case construct: `CASE WHEN count(distinct w.id_work) = 0 THEN 1 ELSE count(distinct w.id_work) END`